# Passing variables of different types by reference as arguments to same variadic parameter

Tags: function, go, arguments, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I've been struggling with *golang*'s lack of optional parameters, so I have been using the closest workaround: variadics.  Even though I got it working, it is messy attempting to pass multiple variable types to the same variadic parameter by reference:

```
// back-end
func UpdateRef(variadic ...*interface{}) {
    for _, v := range variadic {
        if v.(type) == string {
            *v = "New ref val"
        }
    }
}

// front-end
func Interface(x interface{}) interface{} { return &x }
func main() {
    ref := Interface("Hey") // starts as "Hey"
    i := Interface(500)
    UpdateRef(&ref, &i) // ends at "New ref val"
}
```

If I replace the front-end with this:

```
// front-end
func main() {
    ref := "Hey" // starts as "Hey"
    UpdateRef(ref, 500) // ends at "New ref val"
}
```

...then how could I change the back-end to make the desired front-end code work?  The back-end can be as verbose as need be, so long as the desired front-end runs as is.  Is this possible?  If not, is there an elegant solution that requires minimal changes to the desired front-end?

Comment: Firstly, there is almost no practical reason to use a pointer to an interface - especially the empty `interface{}`.

Comment: Secondly, if you want optional inputs to a function, passing a struct with optional field values may be a better route.

Comment: @colm.anseo 1) The reason is that I need to pass-by-reference arbitrary variable types.  Am I missing a way to do this without interface pointers? 2) If I do the struct route, then I will still have the issue of having to perform additional steps on the front-end to pass arguments to UpdateRef, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You can pass pointers (which is needed if you want to update the pointed value) but the parameter type can simply be `interface{}`

Comment: @colm.anseo Based on what you said, I set up a test using the desired front-end section from my above code snippet.  I then set `UpdateRef`'s `variadic` parameter to type `...interface{}`.  I then ran the same for-loop as in my original back-end, except instead of setting `*v`, I set `v = "New ref val"`.  Printing `ref` from my `main` function after doing this, it still returned "Hey", rather than "New ref val".  Am I going about this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `interface{}` as the argument type.  Type assert to pointer types.
Dereference pointers to set the values.

```
func UpdateRef(variadic ...interface{}) {
    for _, v := range variadic {
        if v, ok := v.(*string); ok {
            *v = "New ref val"
        }
    }
}
```

Pass pointers to the function:

```
ref := "Hey"
i := 500
UpdateRef(&ref, &i)
fmt.Println(ref)  // prints “New ref val”
```

Answer (score 2):

you just

```golang
package main

import (
    "reflect"
)

// back-end
func UpdateRef(variadic ...interface{}) {
    for _, v := range variadic {
        kind := reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind()
        if kind == reflect.Pointer {
            reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf("New ref val"))
        }
    }
}

// front-end
func main() {
    ref := "Hey"         // starts as "Hey"
    // To modify a reflection object, the value must be settable.
    UpdateRef(&ref, 500) // ends at "New ref val"
    println(ref)
}
```

check out the golang blog:https://go.dev/blog/laws-of-reflection.

Coding Happy!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  I am marking RedBlue's answer as correct just because he offered a solution that doesn't rely on reflection, but your suggestion worked perfectly and I appreciate the help.